# C++ ios::exceptions throws exception when everything is fine

Tags: c++, exception, ifstream

Here is the code from cplusplus.com/reference

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream file;
  file.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
  try {
    file.open ("test.txt");
    while (!file.eof()) file.get();
    file.close();
  }
  catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My code is very similar

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::vector<std::ifstream *> ifs;
    std::array<std::string, 3> files = {
        "f1.txt", "f2.txt", "f3.txt"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
        std::ifstream *_ifs = new std::ifstream;
        ifs.push_back(_ifs);
        ifs[i]->exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
    }

    try {
        int n;
        std::string line;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
            ifs[i]->open(files[i]);
            while (!ifs[i]->eof()) {
                std::getline(*ifs[i], line);
                std::istringstream iss(line);
                while (iss >> n) {
                    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0 && n % 7 == 0)
                        numbers.push_back(n);
                }

            }
            ifs[i]->close();
        }
    } catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading from files: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ifs.size(); ++i)
        delete ifs[i];
    ifs.clear();
    std::cout << "Files have been read\n";

 // Do something with numbers
 // ...

}
```

The issue is that nothing is read. Exception is thrown almost immediatly. If I comment out `failbit` from exceptions everything works fine, but exceptions are not thrown when the files are missing on Windows. On Ubuntu, without `failbit` exceptions are thrown when the files are missing, and everything is read correctly. But with `failbit` on Ubuntu as well exception is thrown at the beginning of reading and nothing is read. I tried to google it. Found the example from cplusplus.com . And stackoverflow question where the answer was not to check for eof, but instead read this way `while(getline(ifs, line)) { /* do something with line */ }` . I tried this, and got no difference. Before I did these kinds of tasks throwing user defined classes. This time I decided to try standard library for that and it seems like I am missing something.

Comment: The `while` should indeed loop on `getline()`, not on `eof()`.  What error does your catch intercept ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. It would also be interesting if the example from cplusplus.com worked as expected for you. Oh, and the `while(!in.eof())` is a classic mistake, just do some research to find out why.

Comment: Once you have it **working**. You should get the code reviewed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Reading your explanation paragraph is too confusing. You need to write the example in code. Make the code do each of the things you describe in English. Then put comments in where it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: In both cases of `while` loop the explanatory string of exception is `ios_base::clear` . I found the thing about `eof` and I tried `while (std::getline(*ifs[i], line)) { ... ` but it makes no difference. Also, if the line `while (!file.eof()) file.get();` is wrong in this case, why they wrote this code on cplusplus.com/reference? Does it mean that this web resource contains mistakes?

Comment: I just tried example from cplusplus.com/reference . And it doesn't work for me either. I am surprised. This is wrong, the `while(getline(ifs, line)) { }` is also wrong. I wonder what the correct way to use `ios::exceptions` is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set when the end of the file is reached: the lines are read OK. However, once there are no further lines `std::ios_base::failbit` will get set: *that* is how the end condition is detected. As a result, only the first file is being read.

If you'd had output inside the loop reading the file you'd see that the lines are actually read. Since you filter the values read I'd guess you don't see any numbers read because none of the numbers provided matches the condition.

The check for `eof()` doesn't help, of course, as reading the last line will stop reading with the newline character right before reaching the end of file but it won't set `std::ios_base::eofbit`: the bit is only set when EOF is actually touched but that only happens with the next character read.

Since you should *always* check whether something was read *after* attempting to read, the condition `while (ifs[i]->eof())` is ill-advised (and it is a good example why you should **not** use [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/) but rather [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com)). Instead you should use

```
while (std::getline(*ifs[i], line))
```

You might get better results reading each of the files in their own `try`/`catch` blocks. Personally, I don't think exceptions and I/O fit well together and I have never had any production code setting an exception mask. I'd recommend staying clear of setting the exception mask for streams.